# SQL: Having trouble forming a query

Tags: sql

Okay I had a hard time naming this question. But it's hard to describe so went with a simple title.

I have a table called Stock that has:
Stock (BarCode, MagId, Format)

And a table called magazines that has:
Magazines (MagId, Title, ReleaseDate)

There are two magazine formats: Print and Online

Some magazines are available only online or only on print. Some are on both.

I need to Select the MagId for the magazines that are ONLY on print from the Stock table. Then I need to list their Title and ReleaseDate.

So, I've started with:

```
SELECT Title, ReleaseDate
FROM Magazines
WHERE MagId IN ( SELECT MagId
                    FROM Stock
                    WHERE Format = 'Print'
                    AND Format <> 'Online' );
```

I am not getting the desired results. I think because the subquery to select only the print magazines is wrong.

Can anyone shed some light?

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, What is the value for Magazines , that are available in both print and online format in Stock table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have only two formats, you can do this by getting all magazines that don't have an "online" format:

```
SELECT Title, ReleaseDate
FROM Magazines
WHERE MagId NOT IN (SELECT MagId
                    FROM Stock
                    WHERE Format = 'Online' );
```

If you had more than two formats, you could change the `Format = 'Onliine'` to `Format in (<list goes here>)'`.

EDIT:

If you wanted a version that expressed it as "Magazines where the format is *only* `'Online'`" rather than as "Magazines where the format is never "not `'Online'`):

```
SELECT m.Title, m.ReleaseDate
FROM Magazines m join
     (select MagId
      from Stock s
      group by MagId
      having  count(*) = sum(Format = 'Online')
     ) sm
     on m.MagId = sm.MagId;
```

The `having` clause is saying "all formats found are `'Online'`".

Comment: Right yes of course. WOW I think I've been staring at SQL for far too long today because that was really obvious. I need a break. THANK YOU though. Cannot believe how obvious that was. Geez.

Comment: From what I understand this would show results with "Both" as well.

Comment: @Falcon . . . No it wouldn't.  It is *excluding* anything that is "online".  You may be thinking of the form `MagId In (. .  . WHERE Format = 'Print')`.

Comment: what I don't get is, what is if some of them are neither print nor online available?

Comment: @Falcon nope this worked like a charm. Each MagId is listed more than once - some always as Online, some always as Print, and some as Print and then again as Online. So selecting the ones listed as Online picks up the ones listed only as online and the ones listed as both. Then it's a simple matter of using the 'parent query' to Select the MagID from Magazines that are NOT IN the subquery.

Comment: @Sarajog this would not happen in this table. They must be one or the other. not null.

Comment: okay, can't know it, you never wrote this ;)  but for the case you should be able to do it with adding an and: AND MagId IN (... WHERE Format = 'Print')

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure,

```
Format = 'Print' AND Format <> 'Online'
```

condition will become true for any row in the Stock table? Try this,

```
SELECT Title, ReleaseDate
FROM Magazines
WHERE MagId IN ( SELECT MagId
                FROM Stock
                WHERE Format = 'Print');

 Format = 'Print'
```

Above condition will become true,

1. For rows with format value is equal to print

I believe this is what you want.

Comment: he wants the ones that are ONLY print, not the ones that are both.

Comment: Okay, Now Format = 'Print' will only select the ones that are ONLY print.